# Add Mask on md-datepicker angular js

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, mask

---

**I want to add mask input to date picker for md-datepicker in angular js**

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="Date" style="position: relative; right: 24px">
</md-datepicker>
```

I tried following but no luck :( 
    md-mask="19/39/9999" ui-mask="19/39/9999"  MASK="19/39/9999"

Comment: refer this https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Comment: @mayur I have already gon through that but it does not have anything related masking.

Comment: What does that mean? Which kind of "mask" do you want to apply?

Comment: @NicoHaase I want make user to input only in form of MM/dd/yyyy (__/__/____)

Comment: @SwapnilBapat Have you read it carefully bro https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview got to page `CTR+F` and search `Datepicker with custom formats` you will get your solution and right side you can view `source code` for the example working

Answer (score 0):

The following hack is a possible solution.

It uses ng-mask library.

First create the decorator:

```js
mdDatepickerDirective.$inject = ['$delegate', 'moment'];
function mdDatepickerDirective ($delegate, moment) {
    const directive = $delegate[0];

    const template = directive.template;
    const link = directive.link;
    directive.compile = function () {
        return function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            link.apply(this, arguments);

            if (attrs.myMask) {
                const inputNgModelControl = scope.ctrl.ngInputElement.controller('ngModel');

                inputNgModelControl.$formatters.push(function (value) {
                    const tempDate = moment(scope.ctrl.ngInputElement.controller('mdDatepicker').ngModelCtrl.$viewValue);
                    if (scope.ctrl.ngInputElement.controller('mdDatepicker').mode === 'month') {
                        return tempDate.isValid()? tempDate.format('MM/YYYY') : '';
                    } else {
                        return tempDate.isValid()? tempDate.format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
                    }
                });

                const watch = scope.$watch(function () {
                    return scope.ctrl.ngInputElement.controller('ngModel').$error.mask;
                }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    ctrl[0].$setValidity('mask', !newValue)
                });

                element.on('$destroy', function() {
                    watch();
                });
            }
        };
    };

    directive.template = function (tElement, tAttrs) {
        const originalTemplate = template.apply(this, arguments);

        if (tAttrs.myMask) {
            const element = angular.element(originalTemplate);
            element.find('input').attr('mask', tAttrs.myMask);
            element.find('input').attr('mask-validate', tAttrs.myMaskValidate);
            element.find('input').attr('ng-model', "ctrl.dateInput");

            let newTemplate = '';
            for (let i = 0; i < element.length; i++) {
                newTemplate += element[i].outerHTML;
            }
            return newTemplate;
        }
        return originalTemplate;
    };

    return $delegate;
}
```

Then in app.config phase:

```js
$provide.decorator('mdDatepickerDirective', mdDatepickerDirective);
```

Original code: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9976#issuecomment-332529645